# GMAT Get States of Propagation

Tags: orbit, gmat, propagation, api

I am failing with the most simple thing ever:

I want to store the SC states of a Propagation over 1 day inside an array!

So the basic script would look like this:

```
BeginMissionSequence;
Propagate 'Prop' JGM3_18_18(DefaultSC) {DefaultSC.ElapsedSecs = 86400};
GMAT an_array = DefaultSC.SMA;
```

So the question is:

How do I store the SC states of a propgation in GMAT in order to use them in the further mission sequence to calculate sth. In my case I would like to calculate the average eccentricity over this one day of propagation and use it later in the mission sequence.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Cheers

Comment: I don't think you can do that in GMAT itself. You could either export the states using a `ReportFile` or write a Python script that GMAT calls, which would then do this calculation. The scripting language of GMAT is restrictive